# AzDo build pipeline to run the step templates based on conditional parameters

Tags: azure-devops

I have below `main.yml` build pipeline,

```
parameters:
  - name: ListOfEnvironments
    type: object
    default:
      - dev
      - tst
      - acc
      - prd

stages:
- ${{ each value in parameters.ListOfEnvironments }}:
    - template: templates/stage.yml
      parameters:
        environment_name: ${{ value }}
```

Now above template works and able to call different env specific `stage.yml` templates.
now inside stage.yml I have the below structure:

```
stages:
  - stage: deploy_to_env
    displayName: Deploy
    jobs:
      - job: deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        variables:
          - name: environment
            value: ${{ parameters.environment_name }}
        steps:
        ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, "dev") }}:
        template: ../steps_templates/dev_steps.yml
        ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, "acc") }}:
        template: ../steps_templates/acc_steps.yml
```

I'm not able to call steps template based on the conditions. Also, I tried to do like below

```
${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, "dev") }}:
    steps:
    - template: ../steps_templates/dev_steps.yml
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, "acc") }}:
    steps:
    - template: ../steps_templates/acc_steps.yml
```

It's not working, does anyone have any idea how to call steps based on the conditional parameters.

UPDATE:
I finally managed to go further like this, where it recognized the env variable but now it complains `Unrecognized value: '"dev"'. Located at position 33 within expression: eq(parameters.environment_name, dev)`

```
steps:
        - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, "dev") }}:
          - template: ../steps_templates/dev_steps.yml
        - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, "acc") }}:
          - template: ../steps_templates/acc_steps.yml
```

it's working now, after changing `"` to `'` . It's all good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be someone will find this helpful:
The below layout will work fine:

```
        steps:
        - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, 'dev') }}:
          - template: ../steps_templates/dev_steps.yml
        - ${{ if eq(parameters.environment_name, 'acc') }}:
          - template: ../steps_templates/acc_steps.yml
```